# Using the Gauss-Seidel method, will the matrix A converge

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Just came back from my Numerical Analysis midterm, posting up the questions and my solutions for an estimation as to how I did.

If you were to perform the **Gauss-Seidel** method on a matrix $A$, where 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$ will it converge?

I was under the impression, from [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Convergence), that the method would converge if $A$ is diagonally dominant, that is, the absolute value of each diagonal entry is larger than or equal to the sum of the absolute values of the rest of the row entries.

$|A_{11}| \geq |A_{12}| + |A_{13}| \\ |A_{22}| \geq |A_{21}| + |A_{23}| \\ |A_{33}| \geq |A_{31}| + |A_{32}|$

which for this matrix holds. So I would expect the method to converge to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This matrix is not strictly diagonal dominant. However, it is irreducible and one of the inequalities is strict, so it is irreducibly diagonal dominant, and Gauß-Seidel should, indeed, converge.